# node js win32ole installation error

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-2008, win32com, win32ole

I get an error when I'm trying to run this command "npm i win32ole".

```
    C:\NODE JS. EXPRESS\node_modules\win32ole\node_modules\ref>if not defined npm_co
nfig_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\
..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
Построение проектов в этом решении по одному. Чтобы включить параллельную сборку
, добавьте параметр "/m".
C:\NODE JS. EXPRESS\node_modules\win32ole\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxpro
j(44,46): error MSB4025: не удалось загрузить файл проекта. Недопустимый знак д
ля указанной кодировки., строка 44, позиция 46.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\NODE JS. EXPRESS\node_modules\win32ole\node_modules\ref
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "win32ole"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code
```

Is there any approach to solve this issue? I have vc+ 2008 and Python 2.7.1 already installed on my PC with Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I am not sure what the Russian text says.  Google translate says something about encoding.  However, the following could be of help.

From package.json for win32ole:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.8.18 && < 0.9.0"
  },
```

This suggests that win32ole is only compatible with a range of node versions lower than the one you have installed.  My recent experience mostly confirms this.  I was not able to install using node v4.2.0, but I have been able to install using node v0.10.x.  So try lowering your version of node; nvm can be helpful with node version switching.

Also, try

`npm install node-gyp@latest in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\`

I have read of and experienced many issues with earlier versions of node-gyp on Windows.  Updating your version could help; it has helped me.